# Confused with what to use - List vs Table

Tags: html

I've been browsing for about an hour now regarding what the best practice is for this and the majority of what I read is to use a table for tabular data and a list for lists, which makes sense. However, I'm confused about this type of UI:

[image]

So it has columns and rows but its a list of contacts . Can you give your thoughts on what should I use for this type of UI?

(Btw, there's nothing particular in this image, I'm not trying to create exactly this, just needed something to show what I mean)

Comment: just think of tabular data as if the rows in a column under a heading match up to the heading, then it is tabular data, if not, then it probably isn't and you shouldn't use a table.  As for what you should use - it's entirely up to you.  If you don't mid presenting your data that way then use a table, if you want it more responsive, don't

Comment: This has a good section on when to use and when not to use a table (semantic reasons only) - https://www.lifewire.com/tables-for-tabular-data-3469858

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A **table** is appropriate here, since you have semantically meaningful columns as well as rows. HTML tables will automatically handle column alignment (and also provide a `<th>` tag for the table header), and tables will preserve the column information even for users using screen readers, text-only browsers, etc. (which lists won't).

You would want to use lists for e.g. the sidebar, tags, or items in the "Edit Contact" dropdown.